# PHP foreach laravel view

Tags: php, objeto, foreach, blade

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el blade de laravel

```
        @foreach($destinos as $p)
            <div class="col-sm-1">
             <div class="info-group">
              <label>Empresa Preferida 1</label>
              <h4>{{ $p->empresa_pref1 or '-' }}</h4>
             </div>
            </div>

           <div class="col-sm-2">
             <div class="info-group">
               <label>Boleto</label>
             <h4>
               @foreach($pasajes_lote as $pl)
                  {{$pl->pasaje_be}}
               @endforeach
             </h4>
            </div>
          </div>
       @enforeach
```

$pasajes_lote me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1124 (36) { ["reserva_codigo"]=> string(12) "MZMY00658444" ["pasaje_be"]=> string(13) "2222222222222" } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#1126 (36) { ["reserva_codigo"]=> string(12) "YZNM00658944" ["pasaje_be"]=> string(0) "" } }
```

El segundo valor de pasaje_be es un string es vacio, sin embargo en el elemento H4 estoy viendo el "2222222222222" que me devuelve el primer object en la primer posicion del array, quisiera saber como hacer para que me muestre correctamente el "2222222222222" para el primer caso y el " " para el segundo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy un poco nuevo en esto, alguna idea?

Comment: Hola!, en el array veo **2** variables que se llaman `pasaje_be` , lo mas probable es que tome la primera que encuentre `["pasaje_be"]=> string(13) "2222222222222"`

Comment: claro yo necesito que me muestre: para la primera vez [0][ pasaje_be ] el cual vale "2222222222222" y para el segundo caso, [1][ pasaje_be ] el cual vale " " y asi sucesivamente

Comment: Funciono perfecto! muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este fragmento siempre se va a imprimir lo que tiene

```
@foreach($pasajes_lote as $pl)
    {{$pl->pasaje_be}} 
@endforeach
```

puede que esta solución te funcione, la verdad nosabría como hacerlo en blade.php

```
    <?php 
    $index = 0;
    ?>
    @foreach($destinos as $p)
        <div class="col-sm-1">
         <div class="info-group">
          <label>Empresa Preferida 1</label>
          <h4>{{ $p->empresa_pref1 or '-' }}</h4>
         </div>
        </div>

       <div class="col-sm-2">
         <div class="info-group">
           <label>Boleto</label>
         <h4>
           <?php
              $contador = 0;
           ?>
           @foreach($pasajes_lote as $pl)
              <?php
              if($index == $contador){
                  echo $pl->pasaje_be;
              }
              $contador++;
              ?>
           @endforeach
           <?php $index++; ?>
         </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
   @enforeach
```

Agregué un contador en ambos foreach para identificar sus iteraciones, si ambas pertenecen a la misma iteración muestra su contenido